# How to Change Wordpress Admin Bar My Account Profile URL

Tags: wordpress, toolbar, buddypress

My wordpress admin bar 'My Account' links takes the user to the back end to manage their profile etc. There are also buddypress links on that menu which take the user to manager their profile on the front end. I like the avatar with the 'Howdy' but I don't want users on the back
end; so I need to change the WP links to take them to the front end.

I found how to remove links and add links to the admin bar 'My Account' but I just want to change the url of those top links from /wp-admin/profile to /members/user/profile.

admin-bar.php
/**
 * Add the "My Account" item.
 *
 * @since 3.3.0
 *
 * @param WP_Admin_Bar $wp_admin_bar
 */

```
if ( current_user_can( 'read' ) ) {
        $profile_url = get_edit_profile_url( $user_id );
```

Would changing the 'get_edit_profile_url' from a wordpress admin url to the buddypress members url be the simplest way to accomplish my goal? ... and How would I do that to test it?

Thanks to anybody who can help me, I'm not very good with php.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any help with changing the url however this redirect in my functions file keeps the user on the front end.
Thanks to: http://blog.happyplugins.com/redirect-user-profile-page-frontend-page/

```
add_action ('init' , 'prevent_profile_access');

function prevent_profile_access() {
        if (current_user_can('manage_options')) return '';

        if (strpos ($_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'] , 'wp-admin/profile.php' )){
            wp_redirect ('/members/' .bp_core_get_username(bp_loggedin_user_id() ));
            die();
         }

}
```

I'd still like to know how to change the URL instead of using the redirect, if anyone knows how!

Answer (score 0):

```
bp_core_get_userlink( $user_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'rew_admin_bar_remove_wp_profile', 0);

function rew_admin_bar_remove_wp_profile() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('edit-profile');
 }

add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'rew_add_bbp_profile', 999);

function rew_add_bbp_profile($wp_admin_bar) {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user() ;
$user=$current_user->user_nicename  ;
$user_slug =  get_option( '_bbp_user_slug' ) ;
if (get_option( '_bbp_include_root' ) == true  ) {  
    $forum_slug = get_option( '_bbp_root_slug' ) ;
    $slug = $forum_slug.'/'.$user_slug.'/' ;
}
else {
    $slug=$user_slug . '/' ;
}

$profilelink = '/' .$slug. $user . '/edit' ;

$wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
    'parent' => 'user-actions',
    'id'        => 'bbp-edit-profile',
    'title' => 'Edit Profile',
    'href' => $profilelink,
) );

}
```

get you to the bbpress user profile